# VBScript Kill Process Using Parameter

Tags: input, process, parameters, vbscript, kill

I am attempting to create a VBscript that will kill a Windows process that is passed in as a parameter (argument).  I have the following code and believe the problem to be at either line 8, 18, or 24 but am not sure what the problem is. When I replace that code with notepad.exe instead of the variable, it works. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
Dim prcid
Dim check
Dim Inp
Set Inp = WScript.Arguments
check=0
Set objService = GetObject("winmgmts:")

For Each Process In objService.InstancesOf("Win32_process")
  If process.name= "Inp" Then
    prcid=process.processid
    check=1
    Exit For
  End If
Next

If check =0 Then
  WScript.Quit [ExitCode]
End if

For Each process In objService.InstancesOf("Win32_process")
  If process.name= "Inp" Then
    If process.processid=prcid Then
        strComputer = "."
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
          & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
          ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'Inp'")
        For Each objProcess in colProcessList
            objProcess.Terminate()
        Next
    End If

    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a variable as a literal:
1. `process.name= "Inp"` should be `process.name = Inp` (twice)
2. `"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'Inp'"` should be `"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & Inp & "'"`

And you are using the `WScript.Arguments` object incorrect: to get the first argument from the command line, use `WScript.Arguments(0)`

Disclaimer: I did not test your code with these enhancements, I just spotted these errors on first sight. There could be more lurking inside.

Comment: when i added this edits it gave me the error: "Error In Script- 424 Object Required"

Comment: `WScript.Arguments(0)` returns a string and not an object, so you have to get rid of the `Set` keyword else VBScript expects it to return an object, hence the error.

Comment: @user1512885 I assume you created this for a certain reason? the logical way to do this on a Win7 machine from a command prompt would be `taskkill /IM notepad.exe /F` (where notepad.exe could be any process you want).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no extension for Inp because when I ran the script on my windows XP system it worked fine. Also on my system all the process have an extension, except for
System and System Idle Process.  If there is an extension you will need to use it.

Comment: i am running windows 7 so that might be why yours worked. Also what do you mean by extension? i thought this would just select the process name from the list, not need anything else.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos-What system are you on ? – Tom Monti

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the internet it has been tested on a lot of systems
Verified on the following platforms
Server 8        No
Windows Server 2008 R2  Yes
Windows Server 2008     Yes
Windows Server 2003     Yes
Windows 8               No
Windows 7               Yes
Windows Vista           Yes
Windows XP              Yes
Windows 2000            Yes

---

Script name:        WMI_KillProcess.vbs 
Created on:         10/05/2010 
Author:             Dennis Hemken 
Purpose:            This function kills a process by name, 
                    which is running on a special pc in the network.

---

```
Dim strComputer 

strComputer = "." 

fct_KillProcess "acrord32", strComputer 
' or 
' strComputer = "192.168.2.13" 
' fct_KillProcess "outlook", strComputer 

Public Function fct_KillProcess(strProcessName, strComputer) 

Dim objWMI 
Dim colServices 
Dim objService 
Dim strServicename 
Dim ret 

Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colServices = objWMI.InstancesOf("win32_process") 

For Each objService In colServices 
    strServicename = LCase(Trim(CStr(objService.Name) & "")) 
    If InStr(1, strServicename, LCase(strProcessName), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 
        ret = objService.Terminate 
    End If 
Next 
Set colServices = Nothing 
Set objWMI = Nothing 
End Function
```

Comment: I thank you also. - @AutomatedChaos I need to be more careful when testing scripts instead of using a variable I replaced IMP with "pixie.exe" that was just dumb !